# Cartthrob plugin for email notifications based on custom field

Tags: cartthrob, php, extension

I found a plugin on the following site http://becordial.co.uk/expressionengine-cartthrob-email-notification-dynamic-custom-field/ which I have uploaded but does not show up in the extensions list so cannot install. Using EE 2.7.2

Any ideas why it is not showing up?

```
EE =& get_instance();
    $this->settings = $settings;
    }


    public function activate_extension()
    {
        $this->EE->db->insert(
            'extensions',
            array(
            'class' => __CLASS__,
            'method' => 'cartthrob_on_authorize',
            'hook'  => 'cartthrob_on_authorize',
            'settings' => '',
            'priority' => 10,
            'version' => $this->version,
            'enabled' => 'y'
            )
        );

$this->EE->load->add_package_path(PATH_THIRD.'cartthrob/');
$this->EE->load->library('cartthrob_loader');

$this->notification_events = array('custom_field_event'); 
$this->module_name = "Cartthrob_customfield_notification"; 

if (!empty($this->notification_events))
{
    $this->EE->db->select('notification_event')
            ->from('cartthrob_notification_events')
            ->like('application', ucwords($this->module_name), 'after');

    $existing_notifications = array();

    foreach ($this->EE->db->get()->result() as $row)
    {
        $existing_notifications[] = $row->notification_event;
    }

    foreach ($this->notification_events as $event)
    {
        if (!empty($event))
        {
            if ( ! in_array($event, $existing_notifications))
            {
                $this->EE->db->insert(
                    'cartthrob_notification_events',
                    array(
                        'application' => ucwords($this->module_name),
                        'notification_event' => $event,
                    )
                );
            }
        }
    }
}







    }

    public function update_extension($current='')
    {
        if ($current == '' OR $current == $this->version)
        {
            return FALSE;
        }

        $this->EE->db->update(
            'extensions',
            array('version' => $this->version),
            array('class' => __CLASS__)
        );
    }
    public function disable_extension()
    {
        $this->module_name = "Cartthrob_customfield_notification"; 

$this->EE->db->delete('cartthrob_notification_events', array('application' => ucwords($this->module_name)));
    $this->EE->db->delete('extensions', array('class' => __CLASS__));
 }


    public function settings()
    {
    return $settings;
    }



    function cartthrob_on_authorize()
    {
        if ($this->EE->cartthrob->cart->order('entry_id'))
        {
            $entry_id = $this->EE->cartthrob->cart->order('entry_id'); 

 ee()->load->library('logger');


$this->EE->load->add_package_path(PATH_THIRD.'cartthrob/');

$this->EE->load->library('cartthrob_loader');
$this->EE->load->library('cartthrob_emails');

$this->module_name = "Cartthrob_customfield_notification"; 

$event='custom_field_event';

$emails = $this->EE->cartthrob_emails->get_email_for_event(ucwords($this->module_name."_".$event)); 


$totagb=$emails[0]['to'];

 $order_managers_field=trim($totagb, "{}") ;

 $query = $this->EE->db->select('field_id', 'field_name')
  ->from('exp_channel_fields f')
   ->where(array(
        'f.field_name'=>$order_managers_field
    ))
     ->limit(1)
  ->get();  

$order_managers_field_id=0;

 if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
{

$order_managers_field_id='field_id_'. $query->row('field_id');


$email_query = $this->EE->db->select($order_managers_field_id)
  ->from('exp_channel_data d')
   ->where(array(
        'd.entry_id' => $entry_id
    ))
     ->limit(1)
  ->get();          



 if ($email_query->num_rows() > 0)
{

    $this->EE->load->model("order_model");



$order_managers_email= $email_query->row($order_managers_field_id);


if (!empty($emails))
{
    foreach ($emails as $email_content)
    {

$email_content['to'] = $order_managers_email;

        $this->EE->cartthrob_emails->send_email($email_content,$this->EE->cartthrob->cart->order()); 
    }
}



}




}else{
ee()->logger->developer('no data returned'); 

}

}
    }
    // END
}
//END CLASS
```

Answer (score 0):

Eventually used Postmaster and created a hook to send a custom_field notifcation